# Storing custom user roles in JWT for use in React SPA?

Tags: reactjs, jwt

I am very new to React and separation of frontend / backend development (previously my apps are all coupled together e.g. ASP.NET website). Recently i am building a pure React SPA as my frontend, .NET CORE as my backend, ADFS 4.0 as my intranet auth server and my user roles are stored securely in OracleDB.

**My current design is as follow:**

1) React app will acquire an access token from ADFS with the user claims (using react-adal)

2) React app will call my Core backend with the Bearer token; backend will handle the JWT and check against ADFS

3) On authenticated, user role will be retrieved from the database

4) Role will be returned to React app either as a JWT or user object

**Questions:**

1) Should i store the user role in a brand new JWT that i craft myself (and signed with my own certs) from my Core backend (I mainly need the role for routing such that admin can access admin features while normal users can't). I protect my Core endpoints with the Jwt Bearer attribute so i reckon that i will craft my own Jwt token for my API backend to consume.

2) Supposing that i am using the Jwt token to store my user role for my React app to consume, should i store the JWT in the sessionStorage such that the token will be removed along with the session when the user close the web browser? Given that the session will be destroyed when browser is closed, i can set the JWT exp time to a longer period, let's say to expire at the end of the day?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** Keep the user object in redux store, keep JWT in cookies.

If you are getting the user object from your server, then store this user object instead of JWT. You can use Redux to store the user object so that you can access the role and other attributes of the user in any component whenever you want.
Also, you better store your JWT in your cookies. There is a good react package for this `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-cookie`

If you want the user session to finish on browser close, then you can go with sessions. It is a design decision. But, nowadays almost all the websites are using cookies for storing tokens.

Comment: I agree with you that it is a design decision for using sessions. As i am within an intranet env and users are generally authenticated with ADFS, what we are trying to do is have a seamless SSO experience for the users. When users link to the site, the authenticate will kick in, retrieve my user role from the DB and craft a custom JWT for frontend use for the duration of the session. User role can be used either with redux or React context for routing etc. As the user will automatically trigger the SSO everytime, hence we are thinking of ending session when browser closes. Is this feasible?

Answer (score 1):

**Here are the guidelines for ensuring perfect security:**

1. JWT token must always be encrypted and validated by back-end service only.
2. The UI will merely keep the token with it and submit it to the back-end for every request.
3. UI will never be able to decrypt / understand the content (claims) of the token.

The easiest way to do implement this mechanism is by integrating the back-end with **OpenID Connect** service like Keycloak, Okta, OpenAM, ForgeRock, etc

**More information:**

https://scalac.io/user-authentication-keycloak-1/

https://developer.okta.com/code/react/

https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-reactjs-demo

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-keycloak

Comment: Thanks for your comment! As my app is within an intranet environment, i don't have access to other cloud services. However, i am using ADFS 4.0 and using OIDC for authentication. 1) My custom JWT token generated will be asymmetric and signed by my custom cert and every request will be validated. 2) JWT will be stored in session and attached as Bearer token for every API request.

Comment: Perfect! If the JWT is kept in session and is decrypted by back-end for every API request, then that is sufficient for maintaining the role based authorization. If the user role is specified as one of the claims of the JWT, then the need for creating a separate JWT can be avoided.